# Viewing songs list while driving the Regalia

Tags: final-fantasy-15

While driving the Regalia, I like to hear music. There are many available songs and I keep buying new tracks, but how can I choose a specfic song from a list? Going over the tracks one by one is pretty annoying after a while, especially when it's being reset every time.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to pick songs by title the way you (and myself) would like to be able to. The only shortcut in terms of picking music to play is that by holding the left or right D-pad buttons, you will skip to the next album, rather than just to the next song.

[This guide](http://twinfinite.net/2016/11/final-fantasy-xv-how-to-change-music-in-the-car-regalia/) supports what I've said above:

> You can use the left and right directions on the D-pad to flip between songs. If you hold down the button you’ll flip between albums, and lightly tapping it cycles to the next song.